# Django many-to-many serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a model (Source) with many-to-many relation to the another model (Tag) and create a Source objects without duplicating Tag instance in database.
Here is my models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, default='source')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Source(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='white')
    isFile = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    link = models.TextField(default='')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
```

Here is my serializers:

```
class TagSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)

class SourceSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializers(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Source
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'language', 'color', 'isFile', 'link', 'file', 'tags')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        source = Source.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag in tags_data:
            t = Tag.objects.create()
            t.name = tag.get("name")
            t.save()
            source.tags.add(t)
        source.save()
        return source
```

But when I try to create Source object via http request - the object is created, but without any references to Tags. After some researching I found that validated_data in create(self, validated_data) doesn't contains "tags" field, also I found that validate function of TagSerializer not invoked at any time. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was in my requests, without many-to-many relation we can use form-data and all is good, but when we add mant-to-many relation we can't use form-data anymore and have to use only application\json

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_or_create` method to create Tag object.

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
     tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')       
     source = Source.objects.create(**validated_data)
     for tag in tags_data:
        name = tag.get("name")
        t = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
        t.save()
        source.tags.add(t)
        source.save()
     return source
```

Comment: It's a good advice, but it doesn't solve my problem, because I can't get tag name from validated_data, because there is no information about tags in validate data

Comment: Pass tags in validate_data and try it.